# Blur google map after zooming

Tags: google-maps, android-maps-v2

I used Google Map v2 in my app. When I am trying zoom street, the map becomes blur and not clear. I look related questions on stack overflow but I can not find solution. Sorry for my bad english . Thank you

[Screenshot blur map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tze14.png)

Comment: The map only becomes blur after zooming when your internet connection is really bad. But it will eventually becomes clear if you wait long enough.

Comment: My internet connection is not fast. It should different reason . @Androiderson

Comment: When I set Google Street Map to map type , the map is clear. But google satellite and hybrid map is not clear

Comment: Attach a screen shot to the question.

Comment: I attached photo @Androiderson

Comment: did you solve problem @YusufÖnder